# Flag queue not showing own-flags

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, flags, flag-queue

The flag handling queue has recently stopped showing me flags that originated from me. Oddly, the flag counter does continue to show that they exist.

This is problematic because I often use the site from mobile durring commutes where it is very difficult to do decent moderation and flag any posts that I think need moderator attention. Often these get handled by other moderators, but sometimes they are still around the next time I'm at a computer with the time to handle moderation tasks. Not being able to see my own flags makes this workflow much more awkward.

I can understand if there was a system to not show moderators flags on their own posts, but this in the case of them being the flag owner they should be able to see and even handle them as necessary.

Comment: As an adendum to this, although I cannot see the flags, if I do happen on a post that is flagged, the remains of the flag bar at the bottom shows up and I can thumb through next/prev to see other posts that have flags: just not the actual flag or actions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ðear own-flags,

I don't know here you've been for the past few days, but I'm glad to have you back. I'm sorry none of the other moderators gave you any love and you are still in the queue. It's a big bad world out there, but don't despair. I'll do my best to take care of you now that you're back.

Sincerely,
A concerned moderator